# ActiveMQ Dead Letter Queue listen to ACTIVEMQ.DLQ with WSO2 ESB

Tags: activemq-classic, wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to listen to the Dead Letter Queue using WSO2 ESB.

Right now, I am adding something in the queue and this queue times out after 60 seconds and is then sent to the DeadLetterQueue.

What is the best way to listen to ACTIVEMQ.DLQ and trigger a dataservice that will do its magic to the database?

I am new to this and don't really know how it works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This example will helps you to get some idea http://blog.afkham.org/2012/05/dead-letter-channel-eip-in-wso2-esb.html